# Embedding PowerPoint into Wordpress while also preventing hotlinking

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, powerpoint, password-protection, hotlinking

I need to embed an interactive PowerPoint presentation onto my Wordpress Site. I am currently using a plugin called "Embed Any Document", which uses the PowerPoint Online viewer for displaying my presentation.

I display the presentation on a password protected page, but it is unfortunately possible to download my presentation by using a hotlink. If I use an htaccess file for preventing hotlinks, the PowerPoint Online viewer can't find the file anymore.

Is there any way to embed the presentation while keeping it password protected and impossible to hotlink?

Comment: Since you are already using a password protected page, I *guess* it can be done, at least for people that don't have the password. I am not familiar with that plugin however, and thus clueless what kind of requests it makes.

Comment: The plugin simply embeds an iframe from "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=PRESENTATIONURL"

This PRESENTATIONURL can be used to download the file, which needs to be impossible.

I need to find a way to

Comment: I am unsure which referrer officeapps.live.com sets, if it sets any. I can't check that from here. Do you want people to directly include `PRESENTATIONURL`, or do you also want to prevent people from being able to use this iframe url to view the document directly?

Comment: I want to prevent people from downloading my presentation file. The presentation should only be accessible for use in the embedded iframe.

My naive way of achieving that would be to only grant access to the PRESENTATIONURL for officeapps.live.com, but I failed to successfully implement that via .htaccess

Comment: That is a possibility, and I think the only reliable way in which you can do that. The only thing that cannot be spoofed is the remote ip address, which you can match with `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` in mod_rewrite. The biggest problem is, I think, that this is live.com. They run from multiple ip's, and I don't have a list of possible ip's they use for officeapps. You might be able to use `Allow` and `Deny` directives to restrict access to these files (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).